# Is there any setting in Azure AD i need to setup for redirecting after invitation?

Tags: redirect, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm inviting 'guests' trough the Microsoft Graph API like described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/invitation-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

The invitation works and even getting back the response with the `inviteRedirectUrl` I send with the request. But after redemption of the invitation it's not redirecting the user to the URL I send in the request. In fact its redirecting to the base-URL from where I send the request.

So I was wandering if missed some setting or something else in Azure AD

When I set `sendInvitationMessage` to true and let Microsoft Graph do the mailing the redirect works correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the variable where I stored the value for `inviteRedirectUrl` did not get filled correctly. [Hury Shen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11099213/hury-shen) thanks for thinking with me, it gave some more insight

Answer (score 0):

According to some test, it works fine in my side. When I test it with send an email, it works fine. And if I test it without sending an email, if I copy the `inviteRedeemUrl` to my browser, it also works fine.

But when I test it in graph explorer, I follow the link by `ctrl + click`, it will show error which I guess same to your error message.

[image]

It seems when `ctrl + click` in graph explorer, it will decode the `inviteRedeemUrl` first and then go to the link. When it do decode on the `%26` after the tenant id in `inviteRedeemUrl`. It will not recognize the parameters after the `%26(&)` as the parameters of the redirect url. So please copy the link to browser, but not just use `ctrl + click`.(By the way, I also test it in postman. In postman, use `ctrl + click` is ok. It fails only in graph explorer when use `ctrl + click`).

Comment: I don't think its the same issue for me. The redemption seems to work correctly, but the redirection after does not redirect to the url I provide in de invitationrequest. It just redirects to the website I send the invitation from (different url from the ```inviteRedirectUrl``` ). I dont receive any errors when i copy the ```inviteRedeemUrl``` or when I click the link in the mail I create myself.

Comment: Hi @PaulvanOudheusden Could you please provide a screenshot of your request body ?

Comment: @PaulvanOudheusden And could you please provide the `inviteRedeemUrl` in the response ?